# how would I round this sql query

Tags: sql, math, rounding, ceil

```
 SELECT       name, address1, address2, address3, city, state, zip, faxnum, phonenum, emailaddress, 
  odbcadmin.fn_calDist(- 0.03715491813985, 0.9178158214586024, long * 0.0174532925, lat * 0.0174532925) 
  AS distances
  FROM       dbo.Customer 
  WHERE     (odbcadmin.fn_calDist(- 0.03715491813985, 0.9178158214586024, long * 0.0174532925, lat * 0.0174532925) <= 150)
  ORDER BY distances
```

all this code is doing is fetching the distances and then showing them in a microsoft sql table in ascending order and also it has a condition that says only the distances within 150 miles are shown but i have no clue how to round in sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ROUND(*number* , *digits*)

```
SELECT       name, address1, address2, address3, city, state, zip, faxnum, phonenum, emailaddress, 
  ROUND(odbcadmin.fn_calDist(- 0.03715491813985, 0.9178158214586024, long * 0.0174532925, lat * 0.0174532925) ,2)
  AS distances
  FROM       dbo.Customer 
  WHERE     (ROUND(odbcadmin.fn_calDist(- 0.03715491813985, 0.9178158214586024, long * 0.0174532925, lat * 0.0174532925),2) <= 150)
  ORDER BY distances`
```

Comment: if i do this i get an error

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to close parenthesis in the first ROUND. Check again.

Comment: this works perfect thanks =D just a question if i wanted to in the future not have any numbers after the decimal so its like 125 instead of 125.48 how would i do this ??

Comment: Multiple ways to do this...`ROUND(**number**,0)` or `CONVERT(INT,**number**)`, or check out for `CEILING` and `FLOOR` functions of SQL Server...

Comment: yeee i looked into that and found that round was the simpler out of the three thanks for the advice

Comment: done just had to wait till it allowed me to accept the answer